# positive lookahead in htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I want to redirect from `domain.nl` to `domain.nl/nl` whenever a url is entered that does not contain `nl` after the `/`
Here is my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^domain\.nl/(?!nl).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/nl [L,R=301]
```

Somehow it always matches even when putting in `domain.nl/nl` so I end up in an infinite loop of redirects.

Comment: The check on the *path* not containing `nl` should be in the `RewriteRule`, a negative assertion, rather than in the `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just invert the full condition and check to the for the case "not(matches domain.nl and matches domain.nl/nl)", something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.nl [NC] # if the host matches domain.nl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} !^domain\.nl/nl [NC] # but the full url is not matches domain.nl/nl
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.nl/nl [L,R=301] # redirect
```

Comment: somehow gives me a 500 internal server error. i'm looking into it

Comment: Oh, i've left a space after the `!` on second line, that's what causing it (removed from the answer)

Comment: Strange, it does seem to be working in my test environment. Browsers cache 301 redirects, maybe emptying cache would help?

Comment: your solution was right. the problem was a redirect from zend framework that lead to the infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^domain\.nl/?(?!/?nl)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/nl [L,R=301]
```